# py3270.CommandError: No input field

Tags: python, 3270

Logging in and navigating perfectly fine through the Mainframe.
However, after I login, I proceed to access a new page of our mainframe, this page is just completely blank (it should be blank and always has been). I proceed to input "safe", which is required to proceed to the next page, and get the following error: py3270.CommandError: No input field. I have included an image of me manually inputting "safe" on this blank screen.

[Example of empty screen taking an input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdPGz.png)

If I press "Enter" manually, the Mainframe will jump to the next page, and work fine. However, when using my automation code, this is not the case, and input is not possible due to the following error "py3270.CommandError: No input field"

```
def loginAndEnterFrameRegion(self):
    self.emu.connect(mf_host)
    self.emu.send_string(mf_username, 10, 10)
    self.emu.send_string(mf_password, 10, 11)
    self.emu.send_enter()
    # entering region page
    self.emu.move_to(2, 1)
    self.emu.send_enter()
    # sucessfully entered region page
    self.send.string("safe", 1, 2) #crashes here because it cannot find an input field
    self.emu.send_enter()
```

Weirdly, if I breakpoint at the line before it crashes, the cursor is already on cords 2, 1 and I can manually input "safe", click enter, and it works. But it crashes on run.

I have tried other alternatives such as fill_field(), move_to(), send_string() but none seem to provide any different outcome.
I have also tried creating a variable such as;

```
field = emu.find_field()
emu.move_to(field)
emu.send_string("safe")
```

But no luck.
Any extra information needed just ask.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem and I can't continue without writing

Comment: I will update as a solution once I find it. Backlogged this issue as it seems a full blocker for us right now.

Comment: I solved this problem by add prefix C: before hostname ex. Open Connection    C:${hostname}    ${HostAcc.${ENV}}